# QWidget Initialization different behavior in function calls

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qwidget

I have defined a `QWidget` and initialized it to NULL:

> ```
> QWidget* widget;
> widget = NULL;
> ```

Later when a button is clicked, I initilize this widget and call the show function. In subsequent runs, if it is already initialized, i simply call the show function:

> ```
> if(widget == NULL){
>    widget = new QWidget();
>    widget->show();
> } else {
>    widget->show();
> }
> ```

It works fine and i see that widget is not intialized again if it is already initialized.
However now consider this scenario where i pass the widget to a function to do the same thing:

> ```
> void showGUI(QWidget* w){
>      if(w == NULL){
>           w = new QWidget();
>           w->show();
>      } else {
>           w->show();
>      }
> }
> ```

And whenever button is called:

> ```
> showGUI(widget);
> ```

But this time, it is always evaluating the pointer to NULL and always initializing a new widget.
 I don't understand what really changed in this case?

Comment: That's a memory leak. when passing widget, to showGUI, the value of the pointer is not kept in widget. Also, you should consider using nullptr rather than NULL.

Comment: @Pimich is this valid only for widget pointers?

Comment: It would happen for any pointer. Basically, when using a function having a pointer as arguments, a temporary pointer will be used inside the function. As such, if the value of the temprary pointer changes it won't affect the pointer outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `w` is a pointer, but it's passed by value itself. `w` inside the function is copied from the argument, any modification on it has nothing to with the original argument.

You could change it to pass-by-reference, e.g.

```
void showGUI(QWidget*& w){
     if(w == NULL){
          w = new QWidget();
          w->show();
     } else {
          w->show();
     }
}
```